# Invalid Assignment Left-Hand Side

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to assign a class to an a tag via jquery, but this is resulting in an error through firebug that says "invalid assignment left-hand side" on the fourth line below.

```
<cfoutput>
$('.pngfix a').each(function(index) {
var hreflink = $(this).attr("href");
if (hreflink.toLowerCase() = '../Audio.cfm') {
$(this).addClass('audioImg');   
}
});
</cfoutput>
```

Looking around online, it looks like a syntax problem, but I don't seem to see it...

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you put this code into a ColdFusion output? You're not outputting any ColdFusion.

Comment: @Evik: Maybe because of `<cfsetting enableCFoutputOnly = "yes">`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ```
> if (hreflink.toLowerCase() = '../Audio.cfm')
> ```

That attempts to assign a value, rather than check equality. Change the `=` operator to `==` .

Comment: @AustinSlominski: If this answer solved your problem, you should "accept" it to act as a signpost for future readers.